# How to Produce a Sequence of Numbered Statements Outside of Math Mode and Without Augmenting Equation Counter?

Tags: formatting, numbering, line-numbering

I would like to reproduce the following without using the general equation counter and without using math mode. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 \documentclass{article}  
  \begin{document}
 
 \newcounter{gary}
 
 \def\Gary#1{\refstepcounter{gary}{\parindent30pt\par #1 \hfill(\arabic{gary})}}

Consider the arguments:

\Gary{All square numbers\ldots}
\Gary{All non-negative numbers\ldots}
\Gary{Therefore\ldots}

Do you

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think if you `\refstepcounter`, then you can `\label` (3) and `\ref` it.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you! Corrected.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke To generate the blank line after "Consider the arguments", should I use \vspace? How do I return parindent to its original value after the list of arguments?

Comment: @Gary You can use `\vspace`. To tell the truth, there is too little information about the way of using it. Maybe even a theorem-like environment may be useful here, but  I can only guess. `\parindent` is local here. In  the last line of the example, the default value is used again.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke The `\parindent` command is changing the value globally for me. Putting `\setlength\parindent{15pt}` after the last call to `\Gary` restores the correct behavior, but I don't understand why. I'm using the 'article' class.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Oh, I guess it's because I put the `\def` in the preamble.